# What is the difference of a BA/BS in Computer Science for obtaining a Ph.D?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, degree

I have looked around on Google, only to find zero answers. So, I hope someone could help me out with this.

So, for someone aiming to get a PhD in Computer Science (AI), would it be possible to obtain one with a BA in Computer Science? If the degree type doesn't matter, what are the positives/negatives of getting a PhD with an BA/BS.

Thank you,
Ash

Comment: A BSc can sometimes look better on paper to those who are prejudiced enough to not bother looking at what papers you took. But I sincerely hope that in academia, no one would give two hoots either way. You should care much more about choosing a high quality and comprehensive programme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no difference.** There is no global standard for what qualifies as a BS and what qualifies as a BA; it's entirely up to the university.  There is no way to tell from the letters on your diploma how broad or rigorous your degree program is.

Computer science programs in the US, at least in engineering colleges, are accredited by ABET. Those accredited programs tend to give Bachelor of Science degrees. But CS accreditation is relatively new, and neither graduate scihools nor employers really care whether your degree is accredited (except for some government jobs which require accredited degrees by law).

What *does* matter is which classes you took, and how rigorous those classes are (or appear to be, based on publicly available course descriptions/materials).

> If the degree type doesn't matter, what are the positives/negatives of getting a PhD with an BA/BS.

The only advantage of getting a PhD with a BS instead of a BA is that you have one more S in your CV and one less A. This is also the only disadvantqge.

Comment: Indeed!  [At Trinity College, Dublin, the standard Computer Science degree is  a BA (Mod).](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/undergraduate/computer-science/)