What are "BS" and "BA" degrees?
Simply put: what does "BS" and "BA" stand for in relation to degrees? I think they are both some sort of bachelor degree? And what is the difference between them? Where I'm from I've only heard about "Bachelor's degree" and haven't heard of different versions of it.
Take for instance these physics study programs in Norway:

NTNU

UiB


They only say "Bachelors degree" and not if it is a "BS" or "BA". I don't think we have these two concepts in Norway.
I first encountered this here:
What do "minor" and "major" mean (in relation to degrees)?

To my inderstanding, a "BS" degree is more "thorough" (just requires more credits in your area of study), while a "BA" is more "relaxed" and requires less credits in your area of study (so it's easier to get two BA's than two BS')?
Also (as a side note), another thing I don't quite understand: why was there a need to introduce two versions of a bachelor's degree in the first place? I can see why you would want to differentiate between them when you already have two versions of a degree (so employer can see which you took etc.), but why was there a need for stricter/ more relaxed requirements in the first place? Why not just have one common standard for a bachelors degree?

I'm fairly certain this has been asked/answered here before.

To comment on why there is not a single standard, it is easiest to say that the US just does not do things that way. Colleges and universities were started by different people and organizations for different purposes and there was no regulation by outsiders. The differences between a BA and  BS are determined separately by each college or university.

Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19520/what-is-the-difference-of-a-ba-bs-in-computer-science-for-obtaining-a-ph-d

See: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/academia-varies-more-than-you-think-it-does-the-movie#4477

@DavidSmith nails it. For example my degree was technically a Baccalaureus in Artibus (at least that's what they called it in the ceremony). That is what pretty much everyone got, whether studying maths, natural science or english. Usage varies.

@DavidSmith why is the US relevant here? There are institurions offering either BS or BSc or BA degrees all over the place, some of which predate the independence of the USA so I doubt this was something primarily influenced by the US norms. Was it?

BS is a bachelors of Science, BA is a bachelors of arts.  In most places which you get will depend on what you major in.  I say most, as some old universities, like the University of Oxford in the UK will give a BA to almost all undergraduates, even those that study a science subject.
These are the two most common types of bachelors degrees, but other types do exist too in some places.

Not understanding the downvote here. In my math major in a US liberal arts college, I had the option of either a BS or a BA. The requirements overlapped and I qualified for both. I chose the BA. Later at a large State university I had the same option, MS or MA. I have the MA. I never regretted my choice.

@Buffy I didn't downvote, but this isn't a very comprehensive answer.

@AzorAhai-him-, it is, however, correct.

BSE - Bachelors in Science and Engineering. At schools I know of, the differentiator is the accreditation for the different programs. https://www.abet.org/accreditation/ does not do literature programs, for example. Buffy’s BA vs BS choices had different requirements because of different accreditations.

@Buffy My experience was similar. At OSU, I was able to choose BS or BA for my degree in mathematics. There were some differences in the requirements, but they were minor. I got the BS, but I'm not sure going the other way would have made any difference at all in my life.

@TimothyAWiseman, nor do I think it made any difference in mine. It was just consistent with how I thought of myself then (and now).

It's important to specify which country you are talking about.. In the UK a Bachelors in science is a BSc, and a BS is one of the abbreviations used for a Bachelor of Surgery (the others being BCh, and ChB).  My degrees are MB, BCh, BSC.

@JonCuster I guess that's US? The UK has either BSc (science) or BEng (engineering), and a more cross-disciplinary course could be either. The initials BSE in the UK would mainly be recognised as mad cow disease. :)

To add to this answer - Some schools have the Math & Physics depts within the College of Arts & Sciences - so a physics or math degree can be either “bachelor of arts” BA or “bachelor of sciences” BS: https://www.physics.ucsb.edu/academics/undergraduate/majors

I didn't downvote but I feel like it would improve this answer to add that there are plenty of programs where you can choose between different types of Bachelor's. Where I am right now (in the US), the math department awards either BA or BS depending on the coursework you take. The music department has options for BA or BM (Bachelor of Music). A lot of graduate music programs I've looked at have MM or MA and I've seen at least one MS. It anecdotally seems like an oversimplification to say, "In most places which you get will depend on what you major in"

Like David Smith mentions in a comment, there is no central guidelines for what a "Bachelor of Arts" (BA) vs. "of Science" is (BS or BSc).
Some schools may only award one or the other in a given program, e.g., all degrees from the English department are BAs and all from the chemistry department are BSes. Engineering departments may award Bachelors of Engineering (BEng) degrees; and performing arts programs award Bachelors of Fine Arts (BFAs). (Not an exhaustive list of all Bachelor's of _.) Or, a school may award only BAs or only BSes.
In general, there is no way to compare a BA from School A to a BS in School B, School A may call them "BAs" for historical reason, or maybe they are very different after all.
In some cases, a "BS" might meet accreditation requirements that a "BA" does not in the STEM fields.
Sometimes, departments may award both. Degree requirements would vary in this case, but again, next to impossible to compare between schools. Some examples I am aware of:

A BA in math for high school teachers; but a BS for anyone else.

A BS in psychology for research psychologists, but a BA for counselors, graduate study in fields besides psychology (e.g., law, med school).


Broadly speaking the "BA" terminology is tied to the US' history of "liberal arts education," i.e., broader requirements than is common in Europe, such as requiring foreign languages for science students, etc. BSes in general require more science courses, but unless you know the university/program, you can't tell how rigorous someone's science BA was.
The same is somewhat true of master's degrees, an MA vs. an MS is not very informative.

Sometimes at least the distinction is what organizations accredit the degree.

Actually, my BA in math wasn't because I was headed to be a HS teacher (never was). It was because I was also interested in things other than math (my major) such as Philosophy, and took some advanced courses. I chose BA because I thought at the time that it indicated I was a "widely educated" person rather than a narrowly educated one. There was a list of requirements for each degree and I met all requirements for both. Only one degree would be awarded, however. It wasn't a double major, just a choice of designations on my part.

@Buffy Ah yes, I didn't mean to suggest that was the only way programs may divide their degrees. May edit later along with Jon's suggestions.

Re: "A BA in math ...", note that I got a BMath (Bachelor of Mathematics) degree in 1987 from the University of Waterloo (in Ontario, Canada), since it has a Math faculty instead of math being just a department in a different faculty (e.g., Science or Arts). Somewhat interestingly, at the time, computer science was a department within the Math faculty, so computer science students also usually got BMath degrees. This shows there are additional Bachelor designations apart from those you listed, though I don't offhand know of any additional ones.

The BS in math may have required a chemistry class (or similar) that the BA did not. Just tick-the-box requirements of various accreditation orgs.

@JonCuster Whose regulation would that be? I'll add it to the answer, but this was a friend's program, not mine.

There are a number of accreditation organizations. Some are more anal than others about specific requirements. But, my observation is that a BS vs a BA in math would have more hard science (with lab) requirements for example if they were both offered. Otherwise it comes down to which part of the university the department fell under - School of Arts vs School of Sciences.

@JonCuster This program was in the College of Arts and Sciences.

Yeah, just making it more difficult to untangle… who accredited it, one organization?

@JonCuster I dunno, I'm not in math and you're the one bringing up accreditation agencies, haha. Added a note - let me know if you have more specific details to add.

Fair enough. Seems to be a morass of many potentially overlapping assumptions for different institutions.

“only BSes would be odder, but may be out there.” The service academies award everyone a BS.

@cpast Learning something every day

Let me note that the methodologies of pure math and most other sciences, physics, chemistry, etc. are very different. Both are different from the methodologies of the humanities; history, philosophy, and the like. Math "seems" scientific to many, but it isn't. I'll also note that a math department might, in the US, be situated within the "School of liberal arts" or the engineering "School" or others. The "schools" answer to different deans within a university. And, yes, applied math has lots of overlap with the sciences in its methodology.

@Buffy I’m not sure what you are suggesting changing in my answer

I'm just adding context, actually, not suggesting changes.

@buffy gotcha. That is why I said STEM not the sciences

"In general, there is no way to compare a BA from School A to a BS in School B" - my experience is the course catalogs and transcripts are how one could compare, at least one a surface level. Obviously it doesn't help if, say, "Advanced Linear Algebra" at one school covers very different topics from "Linear Algebra II" at another school (hypothetical examples). Still, the programs I have direct experience with have objectively different course catalogs (e.g., Math BS has more calculus than Math BA, Music BM has more aural skills and conducting than Music BA).

@ToddWilcox Yes, I meant "by title alone."

Oh yeah, that's fair. Hopefully, accreditation is keeping things from being wildly different, but the granularity of re-accreditation processes isn't very fine, from what I've seen.

From the question:

They only say "Bachelors degree" and not if it is "BS" or "BA". I don't think we have these two concepts in Norway.

Perhaps not. Still, I suspect Norwegian universities take these concepts into account when translating their degrees. (There might even be more types, like BEng for engineering.) This might be more likely to be spelled out in a central location than under specific programmes of study. Indeed, NTNU's website provides the following information:

Bachelor’s degrees
The bachelor's degree is the lower Norwegian university degree. The English name of a bachelor's degree in the arts, social sciences, music and fine arts is Bachelor of Arts (abbreviated BA). In the natural sciences the equivalent degree is Bachelor of Science (abbreviated BSc) in English. These bachelor's degrees comprise 180 credits and are normally completed in 3 years of full-time study. However, there is also a 4-year bachelor's degree in music performance studies which is worth 240 credits.

I did not find a similar statement on UiB's website, but did find this programme plan document for the physics programme, which spells out that the degree is "Bachelor i naturvitskap" in Norwegian, and "Bachelor of Science" in English. If it's important to you, you can probably get more information by contacting the university directly.

Vitskap is quite correct – it’s the Nynorsk word for ‘science’ equivalent to Bokmål vitenskap.

Here in Australia, a BSc is a Bachelor of Science, a three year degree in a STEM subject. A BA is a Bachelor of Arts, a three year degree in a humanities subject. Longer Bachelor’s degrees, including those that result in accreditation for particular professions such as Engineering or Law are called something else (BEng — Bachelor of Engineering and LLB — Bachelor of Laws in those two examples).

It is Important to note that 3 year degree In Australia is (like many others) equivalent to a 4 year degree in the US. We (or the target cohort) are generally a year behind in age as the the final year of school is generally year 18, rather than year 16.

This is a concept in the school system in "British and British-inspired" systems which I do not know well.
In Europe we have the Bologna system of qualification. It usually creates a 3 years degree (various names, usually derived from the word license), then an extra 2 years degree (Master) and then a 3+ years degree (Doctorate). We also use points for each hour spent on a subject so that you can have equivalences across universities (to some point)
In France, for example, there are schools that try to promote a meaningless "Bachelor" degree (typically business schools).

You should note that the UK and Ireland also signed up to Bologna. In general, countries have paid lip service to the idea of transferability (e.g. by calling a terminal degree a Masters if it takes more than 3 years or counting things in ECTS units), while carrying on doing what they always did to a great extent.

@origimbo I think the PhD track in the UK is shorter, though? A friend of mine got on that track after his BA, while I had 5 years of university + 3 years of PhD (at least that was the plan, it got extended a bit due to unforeseen circumstances)

The most common current STEM path in the UK would be three year undergraduate degree plus 1 year taught Masters(BA/BSc/BEng + MA/MSc) or integrated Masters (a 4 year path, not 5 years, with a whole constellation of titles starting with M), then PhD for at least 3 years. So shorter than most of mainland Europe overall, but as 3+1+3 rather than 3+2+3, not because the actual doctorate is shorter. Having said that, it’s both possible to get a PhD place without a Masters, and possible to sign up for a PhD programme with a one year integrated Masters by Research (MRes)

@origimbo except in Scotland, where bachelor degrees are 4 years

@MJeffryes except when they aren't: https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/degree-routes/direct-entry/ There's also a matching recent growth in Foundation years and non-Scottish Universities to sign up more lucrative international students (see e.g. https://www.kcl.ac.uk/international-foundation), but I realise none of those paths are typical.

In the USA, BS is short for Bachelor of Science degree and is granted for undergraduate (post-secondary) studies focused (majoring) in a technical subject, eg STEM, or social sciences. BA is short for Bachelor of Arts and study is similar in structure to that resulting in a BS, but with a different focal area (major) in arts (typically music, dance, plastic or audiovisual arts) and humanities.
Art schools, like most colleges, are typically of the "liberal art" sort, and most colleges in the USA are "liberal art" schools. The label implies that students are required to acquire a liberal education by taking courses in a broad range of different fields including science, social science, languages and humanities, with additional requirements specific to the choice of major.
The amount of study is typically full-time for four years, roughly the equivalent of 240 credits in a European university. US colleges operate on a semester schedule, with courses running an entire semester and ending with final examinations at the end of each semester (twice a year). Students typically enroll in 4-5 courses per semester. Accelerated or concentrated one-credit courses in the style of those typically offered in European institutions can also be taken in the summer. If one course amounts to 1 credit, a completed education typically requires at minimum 32 credits.  A concentration or major, for instance in chemistry, might require 10 credits in that field, with specific courses, typically introductory ones, mandatory, and electives providing the opportunity to specialize in a branch, for instance Physical Chemistry.

IMHO this is incomplete and even misleading. You can earn a BS in music or a BA in mathematics at some institutions.

@ToddWilcox Hmmm, I don't think it is stated anywhere that what you state is not possible. A BS in an art school would likely focus on something highly technical, for instance art conservation (chemistry). A BS in music might focus on the physics of sound generation. In what sense is my answer misleading?

@ToddWilcox the following is the question: "Simply put: what does "BS" and "BA" stand for in relation to degrees? I think they are both some sort of bachelor degree? And what is the difference between them? Where I'm from I've only heard about "Bachelor's degree" and haven't heard of different versions of it." I gave an answer in the context of what is common in the USA.
